# Android - My Activity breaks lockscreen

Tags: android, android-activity, lockscreen, ondestroy

So I have an activity that goes over my lockscreen. But when I exit it it breaks my lockscreen. Ok, not literally... but I cant successfully LOCK my phone again. I have to restart it. I feel like I am just forgetting to put something in my onDestroy - like I have to reput the lockscreen after its done. Idk. What is the problem?

Lockscreen Activity:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle){
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.lockscreen);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON|
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);//gotta get it to open on lock screen

    ImageView iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.Background);
    //iv.getBackground().setAlpha(50);

    Button close = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Close);
    close.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
        }
    });

    KeyguardManager km = (KeyguardManager)getSystemService(KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
    final KeyguardManager.KeyguardLock kl = km.newKeyguardLock("IN");
    kl.disableKeyguard();

    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
    PowerManager.WakeLock wl=pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP | PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK, "My_App");
    wl.acquire();

    /*Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    adb.setMessage("Testing");
    adb.setCancelable(false);
    adb.setNeutralButton("Close",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            kl.reenableKeyguard();
        }
    });
    AlertDialog ad = adb.create();
    ad.show();*/

    wl.release();
}
```

As you see I just finish the activity. Am I forgetting to do something onDestroy?

Thanks

Comment: According to http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/KeyguardManager.html you should be using http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD to dismiss the lock. I don't have any experience with these classes to know the difference, so posting as a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: The thing is, if I use the dismiss keyboard, i think the thing that is happening now will just continue to happen... since it says it dismisses keyboard and will never appear again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow... its as easy as this:

```
kl.reenableKeyguard();
```

put this is the button that cancels it:

```
@Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            kl.reenableKeyguard();
            finish();
        }
```

Still trying to figure out how to make it uncancelable through the back button though....

EDIT:

Seems I dont need the final on KL. so this is how you would do it:

```
KeyguardManager.KeyguardLock kl;

@Override
public void onDestroy(){
    kl.reenableKeyguard();
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle){
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.lockscreen);
    KeyguardManager km = (KeyguardManager)getSystemService(KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
    kl = km.newKeyguardLock("IN");
    kl.disableKeyguard();
}
```

Just for anyone who needs this in the future.